# Setting SKLabelNode hidden property to NO not working

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, sprite-kit

In createSceneContents (which I know is being called)

```
self.menu = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Futura"];
self.menu.text = @"Menu";
self.menu.fontSize = 40;
self.menu.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.view.bounds));
self.menu.name = @"menu";
[self addChild:self.menu];
self.menu.hidden = YES;
```

and then when a button is pressed this code is being called

```
self.menu.hidden = NO;
```

but even though I am setting hidden to NO the button is not showing up on the screen

any ideas?

Comment: Based on the answers and their comments, your question incorrectly states what is happening. It's not possible to help you, if you are not providing an accurate description of the issue. Please update your question so that it's accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you expect to see when hidden is YES? Nothing. ;)

If you set hidden to NO the object will in fact be visible. Set it to YES to hide the label.

Comment: when I am setting it to no, it is not showing up... that is my problem

Comment: Ah, then you wrote that incorrectly in your question. Have you considered that position is relative to the label's parent? It may simply be off-screen.

Comment: i know this is not the problem, for when i don't set it to hidden in createSceneContents, it shows up exactly like I want it to

Comment: perhaps its parent or grandparent are set to be hidden, too?

Answer (score 0):

The button is or isn't showing up. Change it to yes to hide it no to not. It is no by default. So you should only have to hide it. Then set it to No when you want it to re-appear.

Comment: this is what I am doing. When i set it to NO, it does not reappear.

Comment: are you positive the function where you call the hidden.no is being called? Try throwing a breakpoint into that function and see if its being called. Other than that I would have to see more of the code to give a better answer. Hope that helps.